# Custom configuration in Cordova project

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, cordova, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently working with simple cordova app, integrated with WebAPI server. My question is what approach is best for storing some configuration values in cordova app eg. my WebAPI server address. Now I'm using angular consts, but I can't change them at runtime. I'm looking for something like Web.config in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Angular Constant provider is a singleton object and it can be updated at run time.

Let us say you have a constant provider

```
app.constant("myConfig", {
        "url": "http://localhost",
        "port": "80"
    });
```

This can be Injected to the controller and the values can be overridden at run time as below,

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function (myConfig) {
        myConfig.url = "example.com"
});
```

To answer on how to get remote config when angular bootstrapped for the first time,

```
app.run(function(myConfig, $http){ 
    $http({
            method  : 'GET',
            url     : configURL,
            dataType : 'JSON',
        }).success(function (resp){
            myConfig.url = resp.url;
        });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But I think I don't have access to my angular js files after ant build. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: I am not getting "I don't have access to my angular js files after ant build". Could you tell me why?

Comment: Yes. After my android ant build I have only .apk file. I'm looking for solution that give me opportunity to change configuration after publish app.

Comment: You can use $http service to get the configuration from remote location while angular app bootstraps (ie) inside app.run(). Check my updated code above.